# Java TCP Socket Byte Heap Memory Issue

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, heap-memory

I have a Java TCP Server Socket program that is expecting about 64 bytes of data from a piece of remote hardware. The Server code is:

```
public void run () throws Exception
{


    //Open a socket on localhost at port 11111

    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(11111);

    while(true) {

        //Open and Accept on Socket

        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());


        int msgLen = dIn.readInt();
        System.out.println("RX Reported Length: "+ msgLen);
        byte[] msg = new byte[msgLen];

        if(msgLen > 0 ) {
            dIn.readFully(msg);

            System.out.println("Message Length: "+ msg.length);
            System.out.println("Recv[HEX]: " + StringTools.toHexString(msg));
        }
    }
}
```

This works correctly as I am able to test locally with a simple ACK program:

```
public class ACK_TEST { 

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Byte Sender Running");


        try
        {   
            ACK_TEST obj = new ACK_TEST ();
            obj.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }


    }


    public void run () throws Exception
    {

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 11111); 
        DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        byte rtn[] = null;
        rtn = new byte[1];
        rtn[0] = 0x06; // ACK


        dOut.writeInt(rtn.length); // write length of the message
        dOut.write(rtn);           // write the message

        System.out.println("Byte Sent");
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

And this correctly produces this output from the Server side:

[image]

However, when I deploy the same Server code on the Raspberry Pi and the hardware sends data to it, the data length is far greater and causes a heap memory issue (Even with the Heap pre-set at 512MB, which is definitely incorrect and unnecessary)

[image]

My presumption is I am reading the data wrong from the TCP socket as from the debug from the hardware, it's certainly not sending packets of this size.

**Update:**  I have no access to the Client source code. I do however need to take the input TCP data stream, place it into a byte array, and then another function (Not shown) parses out some known HEX codes. That function expects a byte array input.

**Update:** I reviewed the packet documentation. It is a 10 byte header. The first Byte is a protocol identifier. The next 2 bytes is the Packet Length (Total number of bytes in the packet, including all the header bytes and checksum) and the last 7 are a Unique ID. Therefore, I need to read those 2 bytes and create a byte array that size.

Comment: How are you sending the data from the device? If readInt() returns 1253831317, it seems like you're actually sending the hex values 4B 01 60 05 (which doesn't look like an encoding of "64" that I know of). My suggestions: use something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to verify that the sent data is actually what you expect.

Comment: Data is coming out as HEX as far as I'm aware. Can I adjust my Byte allocation to account for this?

Comment: Is a length of 75 reasonable for the protocol(in case the length is sent as a single byte, this would be the first byte)? Do you know the structure of the data or if the length is even sent?

Comment: What does "coming out as HEX"? Mean? Are you sure that the protocol calls for 4 bytes for the length? As Roger hinted at: the first byte of 0x4b016005 is 75. If that sounds reasonable as the length, then you may need to use readUnsignedByte() to read the length instead of readInt().

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, by changing to readUnsignedByte() I am getting a received length of 75 and a decent HEX dump in my StringTools.toHexString(msg) call. Thank you!

Comment: @Colin: and do you understand why that's necessary? Do you know the difference between readInt() and readUnsignedByte()? If not, please read the documentation for DataInputStream (or more generally for DataInput) to understand why that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the length from the header is about 1GB. Looks like the problem on the other end. Don't you mix low/big endian encoding?

Comment: 1GB is definitely wrong from this device :D If the low/big was swapped, can I account for it?

Comment: Well, big/little endian wouldn't help here, still it would be mess. However doesn't the client send just single byte or BER compressed int as the length? Do you have sources for the client?

Comment: I have no access to the Client source code. I do however need to take the input TCP data stream, place it into a byte array, and then another function (Not shown) parses out some known HEX codes.