# Setting a Java Byte Array Size from Packet Header

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, arrays

A piece of Java code is residing on a server expecting about 64 bytes of information from a piece of hardware, sent via TCP. The packet has a 10 byte header. The first byte is a protocol identifier, the second two bytes gives the total number of bytes in the packet, including all the header bytes and checksum. The last 7 bytes are a UID.

Server Code:

```
public void run () throws Exception
    {

        //Open a socket on localhost at port 11111
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(11111);


        while(true) {

            //Open and Accept on Socket
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

            //Alt Method

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());

            int len = dis.readInt();
            byte[] data = new byte[len];
            if (len > 0) {
                dis.readFully(data);
            }
            System.out.println("Recv[HEX]: " + StringTools.toHexString(data));
    }
}
```

The issue is my readInt() line, that takes the first four bytes, however I need to determine the length based on the second two bytes. How can this be achieved?

And secondly, is my stringTools.toHexString(data) correct to dump the received buffer which I know should be readable as a HEX string?

**Note:** This question has its root here: [Java TCP Socket Byte Heap Memory Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653770/java-tcp-socket-byte-heap-memory-issue)

Comment: The first thing you should do is read all of the method summaries in the [DataInputStream documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).

Answer (score 2):

Only use `DataInputStream` if the other side is using `DataOutputStream` or it's exact format. The integers, for example, may be encoded [big-endian or little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) - `DataOutputStream` uses big-endian notation, if the other side uses different encoding, you cannot use `DataInputStream`. Using `InputStream.read()` gives you more control if you need it.

Now, since the format of message as you stated starts with one byte for protocol identifier, you first need to read that as a byte (`dis.readByte()` or `InputStream.read()`) and either check that the protocol is what you expect or handle different protocols. Then you read the message length, etc.

Comment: Thank you Jira. The incoming format is Big Endian. I understand how to read the first Byte, how would I go about reading the next two to determine how large my Byte array must be?

Comment: If the next two bites are big-endian encoded integer, you can use `dis.readInt()` on it **after** processing the first byte. According to you, it contains total packet length so you'll have to subract legth of the other fields to get payload length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ByteBuffer` to read the `int` in the last two bytes

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
class B {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        // test value
        int a = 1238098;

        // convert it into an arrays of bytes
        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        b.putInt(a);
        byte [] r = b.array();
        // read last two 
        int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{0x0,0x0, r[2], r[3]}).getInt();

        // print it 
        out.println("Original: " + String.format("%32s%n" , Integer.toString(a,2)).replace(' ', '0'));
        out.printf("Last two: %32s%n" , Integer.toString(size,2));
        out.printf("Decimal : %d%n" ,  size );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Original: 00000000000100101110010001010010

Last two:                 1110010001010010
Decimal : 58450
```

However I would recommend to follow @Jiri answer about read using `InputStream.read()` instead of `DateInputStream`